# Vue router always loads the lazy loaded modules on intial loading

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, lazy-loading, vue-router

Here is the lazy loaded implementation using Vue  official router

**src/router/index.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";

const Foo = () => import("@/components/Test2");

const Bar = () => import("@/components/Test");

Vue.use(VueRouter);

export default new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/test",
      name: "test",
      component: Bar
    },
    {
      path: "/test2",
      name: "test2",
      component: Foo
    }
  ]
});
```

**src/main.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  router
}).$mount("#app");
```

Routes work as expected however the lazy loading not working properly, when I inspect the network tab on the first load I can able to see the web pack generated lazily loaded files

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem is the webpack preloadplugin adds a prefetch tag to all async chunks. To prevent this, add the following to your vue.config.js

```
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.plugins.delete('prefetch');
  }
```

Source:
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/979#issuecomment-373027130

Answer (score -3):

I believe You're doing it a little wrong..

If You want to enable chunk splitting and then lazy loading the component for the route, Your approach should look a little like this:

**src/router/index.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

export default new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/test",
      name: "test",
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "bar" */ '@/components/Test.vue')
    },
    {
      path: "/test2",
      name: "test2",
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "foo" */ '@/components/Test2.vue')
    }
  ]
});
```

this will create separate chunks named `'bar'` and `'foo'` that will be lazyloaded only on route entered.

Comment: I've tried the solution but still the same Worked with full restart:)

Comment: First time its worked but after a cache clear load it came again

Comment: Downvoted because it seems that this solution is equivalent to the version in the question except the chunk is explicitly named here.